# How to get type inference through reduce on object with factory methods

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get TypeScript to understand the outcome of my reduce and keep to original typings for the result of my factory methods. Right now I'm getting a `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ fetchSomething: (i: number) => (query: SomethingQuery) => Promise<{ [s: string]: string; }[]>; ...' has no index signature.`

The result of my `generateApiMethods` function is the same structure as the `apiFactories` object literal but `i` already defined. I understand that the code below won't type properly, I just don't know how to get TypeScript to infer correctly.

```js
import { request } from "./helpers"

const apiFactories = {
  fetchSomething: (i: number) =>
    (query: Api.SomethingQuery): Promise<Api.SomethingResponse> =>
      request(i, "/something", query),
  fetchSomeOtherThing: (i: number) => 
    (id: number): Promise<Api.SomeOtherThingResponse> =>
      request(i, `/someotherthing/${id}`)
};

const generateApiMethods = () =>
  Object.keys(apiFactories).reduce(
    (acc, f, i) => ({ ...acc, [f]: apiFactories[f](i) }),
    {}
  );

export const api = generateApiMethods()
```

Comment: The type cannot be inferred from reduce because reduce returns a value that isn't necessary of same type as original array (it isn't so in your case). If you're asking about how to type generateApiMethods properly, please, be more clear, because this isn't related to inference.

Comment: You're right, I should be more clear. I wasn't sure on what actually needed to be typed and how. I got my solution below. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type { ... } has no index signature` is because [`Object.keys()` returns an array of strings](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208), and `apiFactories[f]` where `f` could be any string results in an implicit `any` result, which is disallowed in `strict` mode (specifically `noImplicitAny`). You can fix this with an assertion of `f` to `keyof typeof apiFactories`.

Beyond that I don't think `reduce()` will be able to infer what you want. You are passing `{}` as the initial value, so the return type is inferred as `{}`. That said, you can use a map type to describe your API:

```
type ApiFactories = typeof apiFactories;
type Api = { [P in keyof ApiFactories]: ReturnType<ApiFactories[P]> };
```

Now you can assert the initial value as `Api`, and/or pass the type argument to `reduce<Api>()`, and you should end up with the object type you want:

```
const generateApiMethods = () =>
  Object.keys(apiFactories).reduce(
    (acc, f, i) => ({ ...acc, [f]: apiFactories[f as keyof Api](i) }),
    {} as Api
  );

const api = generateApiMethods();
api.fetchSomething(query).then(...)
api.fetchSomeOtherThing(123).then(...)
```